# Почему после выполнения формы, Django не перекидывает на другую страницу

Tags: django

Писал этот код чисто по документации и не понимаю почему не работает. 
**forms.py**

```
    from django import forms

class YourComment(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField()
```

**views.py**

```
def comments(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = request.POST.get('comment')
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse('<h2>все окей</h2>')
else:
    form = YourComment()
    dir ={

        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'main_page/more_about_good.html',dir)
```

**шаблон**

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"><div class="card"  >

            <div class="row" id="revwie">
            <h3>Оставьте свой отзыв</h3>
            <h4 class="user_name">Евгений</h4>
            <div class="col-10">
            <div class="comment-box ml-2">



            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="comment-area"> <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Нам важно ваше мнение" rows="4">{{form}}</textarea></div>
<input class="pull-right" type="submit" value="Send">



            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

*Пользователя должно пересылать на другую страницу с надписью 'все окей', но это не происходит*

так же можете пожалуйста объяснить разницу между формами связанными с моделями и не связанными

P.S вот для полноты картины. Вот так выглядит форма.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
заполняю форму, нажимаю кнопку send, сайт просто обновляется и все

*Заранее большое спасибо*

Comment: Что значит «не работает», что происходит вместо работы?

Comment: @andreymal смотрите изменения в моем вопросе